# How do I create keep-alive components that all have the same name in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a list of divs rendered with a v-for. When one of the divs is clicked on, a modal will open, displaying more information about the div.

```
<PlayerModal :player="selectedPlayer" />

<div v-for="player in players" ...>
    <div @click="openModal(player)">
        {{ player.name }}
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The modal gathers additional information with a get request and displays the information on modal open. I want to save this information, so that when the modal is closed and re-opened, the information would be cached. I thought i could do this with a `keep-alive` tag. But i don't know how, when the single modal component dynamically renders information from the different divs.

I was thinking I could render one modal-component per div, that way every modal would have its separate keep-alive tag. But the modal components would all have the same name, so i don't know how to activate or deactivate the separate components.

```
<div v-for="player in players">
    <keep-alive>
        <PlayerModal :player="player" :is=" ??? " />
    </keep-alive>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What about caching the get request? if data is already there then return it right away?

Comment: Modify the original data when the request returns the fetched data, and when you click a player, check the extra data is exists. If it isn't make the request. If you don't want to modify original data directly, create a separate object which will contain the fetched data and use player id as the object key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add a key to the dynamic component

```
<div v-for="player in players">
   <div @click="openModal(player)">
       {{ player.name }}
   </div>
</div>
<keep-alive max="10">
    <component :player="selectedPlayer" :is="PlayerModal" :key="selectedPlayer.id"/>
</keep-alive>
```

you can check the cached components by looking at
`this.$children` and the `_inactive` status of the child component itself.

Comment: This seems to work but when a `player` is deleted, that component isn't destroyed. You can check it using Vue DevTools. It looks like it works perfectly when you wrap the keepalive with in `v-for`.